# “Most of them plant based”

Tags: compound-adjectives

> What's remarkable is that so many of the claims made for some of these remedies, or at least their ingredients, most of them plant based, have since been found to have at least some basis in fact.

I am confused by **“most of them plant based”**

Is the word *plant* acting as a verb in this sentence?

Comment: I have edited your post to reflect English orthography. Please note that in English, there should be a space after commas, and that sentences begin with capital letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, plant is not a verb here. It means that the ingredients are derived from plants. A hyphen would have made it clearer ('most of them plant-based'). See the definition of *base*:

> use (something specified) as the foundation or starting point for something.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the hyphen and the fact that this is a good example of how it can help clarify the text.